# Azure CLI creating storage blob container - random error "object not found"

Tags: bash, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-cli

I have a bash script, which uses Azure CLI to create a set of resources in Azure (about 10 in all). At one point the script creates a storage account and then creates various blob containers, shares and queue.  Sometimes everything works fine, other times, the script fails to create the first blob container or queue or share in the list, indicating "Object not found".  Here's the code (names modified):

```
az storage account create -g $GROUP --name $NAME --public-network-access Enabled --location $LOCATION --sku Standard_LRS --output none

containers=("container1" "container2" "container3" "container4" "container5")
for container in ${containers[@]}; do
  echo Creating $container blob container in $NAME storage account...
  $AZ storage container create --account-name $NAME --name $container --auth-mode login --output none
done
```

Sometimes, this works correctly, however most times it fails to create some (usually the first one, but not necessarily) containers with the following error:

```
Client-Request-ID=3ec920ce-3205-11ee-b1e8-10510731bfcc Retry policy did not allow for a retry: Server-Timestamp=Thu, 03 Aug 2023 13:54:21 GMT, Server-Request-ID=9a20e545-3003-0085-7212-c6adf3000000, HTTP status code=404, Exception=The specified resource does not exist. ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.RequestId:9a20e545-3003-0085-7212-c6adf3000000Time:2023-08-03T13:54:21.3663492Z</Message></Error>.
The specified resource does not exist. ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ResourceNotFound</Code><Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:9a20e545-3003-0085-7212-c6adf3000000
Time:2023-08-03T13:54:21.3663492Z</Message></Error>
```

Similar behaviour is observed when creating queues and file shares.

There is no indication of what resource is not found - or why. Nor can I understand why this works some times and not others.  I'm creating the containers in a loop, so if there is a syntax error, it would fail to create all of them, not just some.

To eliminate any possible issues with container names, I tried with literally as above - container1, container2, container2, etc. - same result: failing to create some of them, usually the first one.

I then thought, maybe there is a timing/propagation issue, so I added a sleep of 10 seconds after creating the container - this again did not help.

Any other ideas?

**EDITED to add**

I am nearly certain that this is a timing issue.  When changed the sleep to 60 seconds, most of the times the script works correctly, however occasionally it still fails with the same error.  Based on the comments, this is likely due to the fact that ARM takes some time internally to provision the new storage account.  Yet, if I look at the properties of this storage account, I can only see these:

```
"provisioningState" : "Succeeded",
"statusOfPrimary" : "available"
```

There are no other attributes I can rely on. Yet, even with these two showing as above, the issue persists. Is there a definitive way to validate whether the storage account is "ready" and I can start creating content?

Comment: Are you always creating a new storage account?

Comment: @GauravMantri I'm not sure what you mean. The new storage account is created by the script; then the script creates the containers inside this account.

Comment: Storage account creation is an asynchronous operation and it takes some time before you can create resources inside that storage account. Can you please try by adding a delay between `az storage account create` and the loop where you are creating the storage account?

Comment: I started with 10 seconds delay - the first container failed, the second one created, even though only a few seconds apart; changing the delay to 30 seconds didn't help. I don't think it's a delay issue.  Azure CLI storage account creation seems to be synchronous, as I can successfully issue other commands to update/etc the storage account straight away, without any delays.

Comment: Operations on the storage account will be successful. However you will not be able to create resources inside storage account until the status of the storage account is `provisioned` (or something similar).

Comment: There is no attribute "status".  There are attributes "provisioningState", which has value "Succeeded", and attribute "statusOfPrimary", which is "available".  Despite this, the blob container creation still fails.

Comment: Use While loop with condition till storage account connection string not equal to null, before for loop

Comment: @gauravpatel Unfortunately, this didn't help.  Connection string is not null immediately after the storage account is created - yet the bloc container creation fails

Comment: If you are not too keen on using purely the azure cli you can opt for a bicep template. That way you can let azure handle the dependencies between resources and you won't need any retry logic, sleeps or other workarounds.

Comment: @NotFound Thanks, unfortunately, I need to initiate requests from the client, as I don't know in advance what exactly needs to be created, it's the output of another process, therefore there's no template that I can create.